# basic.types §3.9 /9th point,ISO Standard C++ specification

Tags: c++

Point from ISO Standard C++ specification  :  §3.9 /9th point

> An object type is a (possibly cv qualified) type that is not a function type, not a reference type, and not a void type.

Any one can able to explain this point with programming .(how it fails )

Answer (score 4):

> Any one can able to explain this point with programming .(how it fails )

Bending over backwards, I came up with the following program:

```
std::cout << sizeof(bool(int)) << std::endl;
// invalid application of 'sizeof' to a function type

std::cout << sizeof(void) << std::endl;
// invalid application of 'sizeof' to a void type
```

That is because:

> The `sizeof` operator yields the number of bytes in the **object** representation of its operand.

I cannot apply the same reasoning for references because:

> When applied to a reference or a reference type, the result is the size of the referenced type.

But we can use the fact that arrays are sequences of **objects**:

```
int& array[10];
// error: declaration of 'array' as array of references
```

This is an error because references are not objects. Happy now? ;)

Comment: Can u please explain with object type

Comment: @1User: Well, `sizeof` works with any object type (as long as it's not incomplete), so for example `sizeof(int)` will compile, as will `sizeof(std::string)` and `sizeof(your_own_class_type)`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you making it harder than you have to?

There are various "things" in C++, such as functions, references, pointers, classes, and so forth.  Almost everything has a type (e.g. variables) or is a type (e.g. classes), and some of those types are said to be "object types".  Function types, reference types, and void are not "object types".

Note that void is a special type with several special cases around it.  In particular, it's used to mean "nothing" in function return types, and to mean "unknown type" when used as void* (a "pointer to an unknown type").

"Reference types" should be fairly self-explanatory: add a & to an existing type to get a reference type.  (You can't do this with all types.)

Function types is also exactly as it sounds: the type of a function.  For example:

```
void f();
int h(double);
```

Here, f has type void() and h has type int(double).  (Function types look weird compared to most other types.)